# Keyboard mappings don't seem to match selected layout

Tags: keyboard

I've installed Raspian Jessie via raspbian-ua-netinst, but the keyboard mappings don't seem to work how i expect them to.

I've set the Keyboard to Uk English via `sudo raspi-config -> Localisation Options -> Change Keyboard Layout`

I've selected the right style (generic 102-key) and English UK. When I do this i get a couple of lines of `update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults` - which i have seen mixed reports of being an issue or not.

However some notable key mappings are wrong:

- Shift-2 produces @ instead of "
- Shift-3 produces # instead of £
- Shift-\ produces > instead of |

which seems to point at it being set to US English, or at least certainly not UK

The config file in /etc/default/keyboard has the correct settings in it from raspi-config so it seems that I'm missing a config file somewhere and/or raspi-config is editing the wrong thing.

What is going on? Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you reboot Raspberry pi after changing keyboard setup?

Comment: i have rebooted since the settings change, and no change.